# Spring data page object json response not having reference object info

Tags: spring

I have an Org entity which has FK relation with OwnerGroup entity.

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"appName","appId"}))
public class Org {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int Id;

    /*@GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_org_id", strategy = "com.ciphercloud.ae.generators.OrgIdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_org_id")  
    @Column(name="Org_Id")
    private String orgId;*/

    @NotEmpty (message = "org username is mandatory")
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty (message = "org password is mandatory")
    private String password;

    private String securityToken;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_app_id", strategy = "com.ciphercloud.ae.generators.AppIdGenerator")
    private String appName;

    private String appId;

    @NotBlank (message = "Org Category should not be null or empty")
    private String orgCategory;

    private String orgSubCategory;

    @NotBlank (message = "org regionId should not be null or empty")
    private String regionId;

    @Transient
    private int parent_org_id;


    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_org_id")
    private Org org;

    @NotBlank (message = "Org Type should not be null or empty")
    private String orgType;

    @Transient
    private int ownergroup_id;

@ManyToOne ( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn( name = "ownergroup_id")
    private OwnerGroup ownerGroup;
```

My repository class looks like

```
public interface OrgRepostiory extends JpaRepository<Org, Serializable> {
    public List<Org> findByOrgType(@Param("orgtype") String orgType);
    public Page<Org> findByOrgTypeIn(@Param("orgtype") List<String> orgType, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I have a controller class to expose them as REST and the code is as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Org>> testmap(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> params) {

        System.out.println("params........" + params);

        List<Org> orgs = orgServiceImpl.search(params);
        if (orgs == null || orgs.size()==0) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Invalid search criteria ");
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Org>>(orgs, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }


@RequestMapping(value = "/filter/{pageNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<PagedResources<org.springframework.hateoas.Resource<Org>>> filter(@PathVariable Integer pageNumber, @RequestParam HashMap<String, List<String>> params) {

        System.out.println("params........" + params);

        if(pageNumber <= 0){
            pageNumber = 1;
        }

        Page<Org> orgs = orgServiceImpl.filter(pageNumber, params);
        if (orgs == null || orgs.getSize()==0) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Invalid filter criteria ");
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>( pagedResourceAssembler.toResource(orgs), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

Now when I test the request in Rest Client for the

```
request = > http://localhost:8080/orgs/filter/1?orgtype=Production
```

Its getting the following output.

```
// response
{
username: "testdemo8"
password: "testpwd1"
securityToken: "testkey1"
appName: null
appId: null
orgCategory: "Admin"
orgSubCategory: null
regionId: "na15"
parent_org_id: 0
available: true
inductionStatus: null
orgType: "Production"
ownergroup_id: 0
id: 32
active: false
}-
-
}-
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/orgs/filter/1?orgtype=Production"
}-
}
```

without pagination

```
request =>   http://localhost:8080/orgs/search?orgtype=Production

// response
{
username: "testdemo8"
password: "testpwd1"
securityToken: "testkey1"
appName: null
appId: null
orgCategory: "Admin"
orgSubCategory: null
regionId: "na15"
parent_org_id: 0
available: true
inductionStatus: null
orgType: "Production"
ownergroup_id: 0
**ownerGroup: {
name: "sfdc-ft"
description: "4.5 release"
id: 1
}-**
id: 32
active: false
}
```

If we observe, when page object is not used, its returning the child table data.

But when I use pagination, it's not returning the child table data.

Is any thing needs to add to get the child table information when we use paging?

Comment: can any one please answer ???

Answer (score 0):

I debug the issue and found that Join data is getting trimmed by pagedResourceAssembler class which is using in the controller class. I replaced with

return new ResponseEntity>(orgs, HttpStatus.OK)

Now its getting reference object data as well as expected.